# How Can i use one PickerView for few buttons showing different's data

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uipickerview

I am using one `UIPickerView` for few buttons and when I press on the first button it shows me the correct data but the problem is when I press in the second and the third and the rest buttons it showing me the same data of the first button not the data which is connected to each button. I tried many things but it's still doesn't work. I don't know what is the problem if someone can help me I would be

```
class SearchBuyVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var optionV: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainPV: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var typePV: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var PricePV: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceMaxPV: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var buildMinPV: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var buildMaxPV: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tenurePV: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet weak var doneBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var typeBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var minPriceBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var maxPriceBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buildMinBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tenureBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buildMaxBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var bedView: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bathView: UILabel!


    var optionSelector = 0
    let searchData = ["Search by Areas", "Search by Map", "Search by LRT/MRTs", "Search by Schools", "Search by Propery Name"]
    let typeData = ["All Residential", "All Commerical"]
    let minPriceData = ["Any", "100 k", "200 k", "300 k", "400 k", "500 k", "600 k", "700 k", "800 k", "900 k"]
    let maxPriceData = ["Any", "700 k", "800 k", "900 k", "1 m", "2 m", "4 m", "6 m", "8 m", "10 m"]
    let buildMinData = ["Any", "500", "1,000", "1,500", "2,000", "2,500", "3,000", "3,500"]
    let buildMaxData = ["Any", "4,000", "4,500", "5,000", "6,000", "8,000", "10,000", "20,000"]
    let tenureData = ["Any", "Freehold", "Leasehold", "MalayReserve Land"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpNav(arrowType: 2)
        mainPV.delegate = self
        typePV.delegate = self
        PricePV.delegate = self
        priceMaxPV.delegate = self
        buildMinPV.delegate = self
        buildMaxPV.delegate = self
        tenurePV.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }
    @IBAction func selectOptionsPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        openOptions()
    }
    @IBAction func typeOptionPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        openOptions()
    }
    @IBAction func minPriceOptionPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        openOptions()
    }
    @IBAction func maxPriceOptionPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        openOptions()
    }
    @IBAction func buildMaxOptionPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        openOptions()

    }
    @IBAction func buildMinOptionPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        openOptions()
    }

    @IBAction func donePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        switch optionSelector {
        case 0:
            FiltersController.instance.showAreaFilter(nc: self.navigationController!)
        case 1:
            FiltersController.instance.showMapFilter(nc: self.navigationController!)
        case 2:
            FiltersController.instance.showTrainStations(nc: self.navigationController!)
        case 3:
            FiltersController.instance.showSchoolFilter(nc: self.navigationController!)
        default:
            FiltersController.instance.showNameFilter(nc: self.navigationController!)
        }
        closeOptions()
    }

    func openOptions() {
        optionV.isHidden = false
        mainPV.isHidden = false
        doneBtn.isHidden = false
        typePV.isHidden = false
        PricePV.isHidden = false
        priceMaxPV.isHidden = false
        buildMinPV.isHidden = false
        buildMaxPV.isHidden = false
        tenurePV.isHidden = false
    }

    func closeOptions(){
        optionV.isHidden = true
        mainPV.isHidden = true
        doneBtn.isHidden = true
        typePV.isHidden = true
        PricePV.isHidden = true
        priceMaxPV.isHidden = true
        buildMinPV.isHidden = true
        buildMaxPV.isHidden = true
        tenurePV.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func nextPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        ListingController.instance.showBuyListing(nc: self.navigationController!)
    }
}

extension SearchBuyVC: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {

        if pickerView.tag == 0{
            return searchData.count
        }
        if pickerView.tag == 1{
            return typeData.count
        }
        if pickerView.tag == 2{
            return minPriceData.count
        }
        if pickerView.tag == 3{
            return maxPriceData.count
        }
        if pickerView.tag == 4{
            return buildMinData.count
        }
        if pickerView.tag == 5{
            return buildMaxData.count
        }
        if pickerView.tag == 6{
            return tenureData.count
        }

        return 0

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        if pickerView.tag == 0{
            return searchData[row]
        }
        if pickerView.tag == 1{
            return typeData[row]
        }
        if pickerView.tag == 2{
            return minPriceData[row]
        }
        if pickerView.tag == 3{
            return maxPriceData[row]
        }
        if pickerView.tag == 4{
            return buildMinData[row]
        }
        if pickerView.tag == 5{
            return buildMaxData[row]
        }

        if pickerView.tag == 6{
            return tenureData[row]
        }

        return ""
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        if pickerView.tag == 0{
            searchBtn.setTitle(searchData[row], for: .normal)
            if pickerView.tag == 1{
                typeBtn.setTitle(typeData[row], for: .normal)
            }
            if pickerView.tag == 2{
                minPriceBtn.setTitle(minPriceData[row], for: .normal)
            }
            if pickerView.tag == 3{
                maxPriceBtn.setTitle(maxPriceData[row], for: .normal)
            }
            if pickerView.tag == 4{
                buildMinBtn.setTitle(buildMinData[row], for: .normal)
            }
            if pickerView.tag == 5{
                buildMaxBtn.setTitle(buildMaxData[row], for: .normal)
            }
            if pickerView.tag == 6{
                tenureBtn.setTitle(tenureData[row], for: .normal)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use https://github.com/kmcgill88/McPicker-iOS to populate data in UIPickerView. It is easy to use. :)

Comment: Are you sure you have set the tags of all picker view outlets from the xib/ storyboard correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Have only one picker view and change the datasource on button actions. Then reload pickerview.

Create selectedBtn variable to store currently selected button reference and tempArr variable to store currently selected button's data to show in picker view.

```
class SearchBuyVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    @IBOutlet weak var doneBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var typeBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var minPriceBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var maxPriceBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buildMinBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tenureBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var buildMaxBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var bedView: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bathView: UILabel!

    var optionSelector = 0
    let searchData = ["Search by Areas", "Search by Map", "Search by LRT/MRTs", "Search by Schools", "Search by Propery Name"]
    let typeData = ["All Residential", "All Commerical"]
    let minPriceData = ["Any", "100 k", "200 k", "300 k", "400 k", "500 k", "600 k", "700 k", "800 k", "900 k"]
    let maxPriceData = ["Any", "700 k", "800 k", "900 k", "1 m", "2 m", "4 m", "6 m", "8 m", "10 m"]
    let buildMinData = ["Any", "500", "1,000", "1,500", "2,000", "2,500", "3,000", "3,500"]
    let buildMaxData = ["Any", "4,000", "4,500", "5,000", "6,000", "8,000", "10,000", "20,000"]
    let tenureData = ["Any", "Freehold", "Leasehold", "MalayReserve Land"]
    var tempArr = [String]()
    var selectedBtn = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
    }

    @IBAction func allButtionActions(_ sender: UIButton) {
        selectedBtn = sender

        if sender == typeBtn {
            tempArr = typeData
        } else if sender == minPriceBtn {
            tempArr = minPriceData
        } else if sender == maxPriceBtn {
            tempArr = maxPriceData
        } else if sender == buildMinBtn {
            tempArr = buildMinData
        } else if sender == tenureBtn {
            tempArr = tenureData
        } else if sender == buildMaxBtn {
            tempArr = buildMaxData
        }
        pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        pickerView.isHidden = false

    }
}

extension SearchBuyVC: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return tempArr.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return tempArr[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        selectedBtn.setTitle(tempArr[row], for: .normal)
    }
}
```